# How to check whether the target of a directory symbolic link exists?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, filesystems, symlink

I'm developing a Windows application that targets Windows XP.

My app needs to resolve symbolic links to files and folders. To check whether the target exists, I can use `CreateFile` for symbolic links to files. But after I searched Google and MSDN for a whole day, I found that if I need to get the handle of a directory, I need to use the flag `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`. This requires my application to request higher privileges. I know many users are not happy with this behavior, so I need to find another way to check whether the target of a directory symbolic link exists.

I have also read [Symbolic Link Effects on File Systems Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/symbolic-link-effects-on-file-systems-functions). The other functions I can use to test for the existence of a file or directory all check the symbolic link itself, not its target. I have tried some functions like `_access_s`. They also only check the symbolic link itself.

So my question is whether there is any way to check whether the target of a directory symbolic link exists without requiring higher privileges.

Comment: The user wouldn't even know you'd changed your privilege level. It doesn't trigger a UAC prompt or anything.

Comment: @JonathanPotter You mean `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` won't trigger UAC even if they are logged in as normal users rather than the administrator?

Comment: Correct, those privileges can be set programmatically, they don't require elevation or an administrator token.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have tested it, you are right! Please post your comment into answer so that I could accpet it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that XP doesn't support symlimks?

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` not require any privilege

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, just mention it to avoid use API doesn't support XP.

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I have tested it, I was just confused by MSDN, it said something about privileges. Thanks!

Comment: @zzy this is only bad win32 api (CreateFile) design. if you use `NtOpenFile` here - no any problems at all. anyway you can select open symlink/mountpoint itself or it target, query it attributes, query `FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT`

Comment: @JonathanPotter those privileges ( `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` ?) have only not filtered admin token. thay can not be enabled if not exist in token. but anyprivilege not need here at all

Comment: Normally `CreateFileW` uses the [`NtCreateFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile) option `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE`. But with `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` it does not, so we can open a directory. However, it does use the option `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT`. This has no effect if our effective token (primary or impersonation) doesn't contain either SeBackupPrivilege or SeRestorePrivilege in the enabled state. If your context should't invoke this privileged level of file access, make sure they're disabled in your effective token.

Comment: `CreateFile` will request at least synchronize and read-attribute access even if we request 0 desired access, but we know the target does exist if the call fails with an access-denied (5) error instead of a file-not-found (2) error. That said, the target could be in a deleted state with open handles. In that case it technically exists but will never be accessible by the caller unless the delete disposition is cleared using one of the open handles that has delete access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could use `CreateFile` for symbolic file to get the file handle and
>   then check the file is exist or not.

If `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` is not specified in call `CreateFile` and you get file handle this mean that symbolic link/mount point target is exist. so already not need check something. if call fail because target not exist last error will be `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` or `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (may be also `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME`)

about `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` - this is very bad design of [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) api. this api internal call [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile). the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` mapped to `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` *CreateOptions* flag. this flag checked inside [`IopCheckBackupRestorePrivilege`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/parse.c#L2517)

> This function will determine if the caller is asking for any accesses
>   that may be satisfied by Backup or Restore privileges, and if so,
>   perform the privilege checks.  If the privilege checks succeed, then
>   the appropriate bits will be moved out of the RemainingDesiredAccess
>   field in the AccessState structure and placed into the
>   PreviouslyGrantedAccess field.
>
> **Note that access is not denied if the caller does not have either or both of the privileges, since he may be granted the desired access via
>   the security descriptor on the object.**

so even if caller have not either or both of the Backup or Restore privileges this not create problems.

but [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile) have the next 2 options: `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` and `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE` - this let specify are we want create/open file or directory. if we (potential) create new item - we need specify are we want create directory (`FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` must be set) or not directory (`FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE`, but by default assume this case - so optional). when we open file - both this flags is optional - if we not specify both - this mean that we not care are we open file or directory. if we care about this - need specify one of this flags.

but if look to `CreateFile` visible that not exist option which explicity mapped to `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` or `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE`. the `CreateFile` use for this .. `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` option. this is very not logical from my view, but as is. when `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` not set `CreateFile` pass `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE` option for `NtCreateFile`. when it set - pass `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` and **not pass** `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE`. this allow you open file or directory. and no option for set `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` - because this `CreatrFile` can not create new directory.

so instead have separate option for `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` and `FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE`, `CreateFile` abuse `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` wich have double sense here

Comment: `CreateFileW` can create a new directory, but it's not documented. Use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` with disposition `CREATE_NEW` if you need to create a directory and get a handle for it in one atomic operation.

Comment: @eryksun - even dont know that this combination of flags/attributes force `CreateFileW` pass `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` to `NtCreateFile`. but i think this is too not native. if i personally want create directory - i will be use `NtCreateFile` with `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` option

Comment: @eryksun - now check, yes, with exactly this combination `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` passed to `NtCreateFile`. but what if we say want create new or open existing directory ? with `OPEN_ALWAYS` ( `FILE_OPEN_IF`) already no `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` flag

Comment: Sure, it's undocumented and of limited use. The other use of POSIX semantics for `CreateFileW` was to create/open files without the `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag. But that's been broken since XP by a default-enabled flag in the registry that forces case-insensitive file access. So otherwise `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` is useless.